# Memory management when the ios app is in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to the official tutorial, the iOS application has several main states, such as foreground, background, and suspended state. An app in use whose view page is at the top of the screen is the foreground state.Then, when the home button is pressed or other applications are used, the APP is in the background state. After that, depending on the mobile phone system resources, the suspended APP may be killed at any time. This is the information that can be found online.

Next was the problem I encountered. After being in the background for a long time, I entered the app I developed again and found that I went directly to the last used view page(The picture was attached below. When using the app in the foreground, the username of the currently logged in user was displayed under the avatar. When returning from the background to the foreground, the username under the avatar became empty). This means that the APP has not been killed, but the data on the page is lost, and some of the data in the memory is partially lost too. It feels that the memory related to the app is partially recovered by the system.This makes me very confused.

I did't do any work about the state preservation and restoration process. I did't need to remember the status information of the previous use of the app when I relaunch the app. All I need is to ensure that the memory occupied by the app is fully restored when the app returns to the foreground from the background.

tips:The background in the expression of returning from the background to the foreground mentioned above, indicates the background or suspended state

[view when app back to the foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEAkb.jpg)

here is my code in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if(launchOptions != nil) {
       /*remote message push related code*/
    }

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - APNS
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    /**/
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler {
   /*processing code when receiving a message push*/
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{
    /*processing code when receiving a message push*/
}


#pragma mark - application state
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.isRunningForeground = NO;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.isRunningForeground = YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

}
```

My iphone is 6sp running iOS 11. I develop app with ARC.

Comment: we can't solve problem without some your implemented code in Appdelegate. so please share code and make video of your problem.

Comment: Also mention the programming language tag which is used by you. like if you doing in Objective C or Swift then tag question with that tags.

Comment: It sounds like you have opted in to state restoration but not implemented it fully, so iOS restores the state that it can (the view controller and its views). Up you don't have code to populate the data into the view controller

Comment: Sagar suggested you share your code with us. Please *don’t* do that, but instead create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead. We don’t want to wade through tons of code for a general problem like this.

Comment: FYI, your discussion above seems to conflate “suspended” and “background” states, tho that’s not immediately relevant here. I suspect that Paul is right, that you’ve got an incomplete “state restoration” implementation.

Comment: @Sagar koyani  I have posted the code